# Test public method that calls internal methods depending on input

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

So we have this method here that is accessible by the rest of the system which calls underlying methods according to the input.

```
public SomeReturnObj doSomethingWithInputs(List<Input> inputs) {
  for(Input input : inputs) {
    if(input.getName().equals("A") {
        handleAInput(input);
    }
    else if(input.getName().equals("B") {
        handleBInput(input);
    }
    else { ... }
  }

  // ...
}
```

To get a good code coverage, I would like to test, that if I put a list with two `Inputs` with name `A` and three with name `B`, the corresponding internal methods are called twice or three times, respectively.

So I've tried the following:

```
@Test
public void separatingInputsByName() {
    Input entry1 = mock(Input .class);
    Input entry2 = mock(Input .class);
    Input entry3 = mock(Input .class);

    doReturn("A").when(entry1).getName();
    doReturn("A").when(entry2).getName();
    doReturn("B").when(entry3).getName();

    ClassUnderTest sut = mock(ClassUnderTest .class);

    sut.doSomethingWithInputs(Arrays.asList(entry1, entry2, entry3));

    verify(sut).handleAInput(entry1);
    verify(sut).handleAInput(entry2);
    verify(sut).handleBInput(entry3);
}
```

Unfortunately this does not lead to a proper invocation of the internal methods, probably because the class under test is mocked, so the method implementation is different.

How can I test/verify a method like this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `spy()`, not `mock()`.

When you use `mock()`, all methods are "overriden" so that default actions are taken instead of calling the real methods; `spy()` will simply register method invocations.

Therefore:

```
ClassUnderTest sut = spy(new ClassUnderTest(...));

sut.doSomethingWithInputs(Arrays.asList(entry1, entry2, entry3));

verify(sut).handleAInput(entry1);
verify(sut).handleAInput(entry2);
verify(sut).handleBInput(entry3);
verifyNoMoreInteractions(sut); // if necessary
```

Also, you can:

```
when(entry1.getName()).thenReturn("A");
```

Personally, I find it easier to read, but that's a matter of taste, of course.

Also, you can use `InOrder` in your case:

```
final InOrder inOrder = inOrder(sut);

inOrder.verify(sut).handleAInput(entry1);
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. I don't really need `inOrder` in this case, but might be useful in the future. I have stubbed both methods to `return null` to prevent side effects when constructing the SUT. Is that a valid way to do this?

Comment: Not sure what side effects you mean here?

Comment: I got an NPE in one of the internal methods, since an internal class is mocked because it accesses the database. Of course, getting something from a mock DAO returns null if it is not specified and all further actions on that object lead to an NPE. Thus, I just want the internal methods to do nothing (in this test case), I just want to make sure they are being called.

Comment: Well, you can use `when` in conjuction with spies... For instance, `doNothing().when(sut.handleA())`

Comment: Ah, mockito is so wonderful. Thank you very much for the insight.